# I want to use Persian calendar, what should I change?

Tags: php, laravel, backend, octobercms, persian-calendar

In this section, I want to use the Persian calendar,
This form is for a component. What should I change? What should I write to show me this component of the Persian calendar?

```html
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="date">date</label>
    <input id="date" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" type="text" value="{{ post.date }}"/>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: salaam. I think you should use a JS library/plugin. Do you have any?

Comment: I texted you via Skype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Persian datepicker like the given link:
https://behzadi.github.io/persianDatepicker/